# How do I convert a project from targeting .net core to target framework to a .net standard?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I created a new .net core 3.1 project and built it using VS2019 16.4.4

Now I want to change it to .Net Standard.

I know to go to the project properties and select the Target framework combo.

[image: choose framework]

However no Standard framework options appear.

If I select Install other frameworks then I am taken to [The download .Net SDKs for Visual Studio page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral)

However the SDK I want is already installed on my machine.

Why am I not seeing what I want in the combo box.?

Comment: because .Net Core and .Net Standard are different concepts, the same question is why you don't see .Net Framework here

Comment: So how should I go about converting ?

Comment: I had the same issue and i finished with creating separate .Net Standard project and copied all files from .Net Core to it.

Comment: I tried that and ran into trouble trying to figure out where to get Newtonsoft from. In core I have it in a Microsoft package I aren't sure which one

Comment: https://blog.todotnet.com/2017/07/net-standard-and-net-core/

Comment: you can get Newtonsoft.JSON from nuget package manager, however it will target .NET Standard library instead of Core, so it might not work for your other packages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207476/discussion-between-pwrigshihanomoronimo-and-kirsten-greed).

Comment: I will investigate. You have answered the question. Care to write it up? Microsoft could have organised a better user experience in this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Standard, like .NET Core and .NET Framework, is separate framework, so you can't switch that easily. You would need to create separate project targeting .NET Standard. Once you do it, you will see other options in 'Target framework'.

Worth to mention, you can't reference .NET Core and .NET Framework projects from your .NET Standard library, since .NET Standard is just an abstraction which is built differently depending on the executing environment (.NET Core or Framework)

[image]

Comment: Microsoft could have handled this UI better. i.e better help about changing frameworks at this point.